# Запуск программы на удаленном компьютере

Tags: python

Мне нужно запустить .bat файл из питона(по определенному условию) на компьютере(вин10) к которому я имею доступ по сети.
Те работает питоновский скрипт на сервере , он дожен запустить файл удаленно.
Я так понимаю нужен запущенный скрипт на принимающем компьюторе. Какими средствами это делается?

Comment: https://github.com/jborean93/pypsexec#examples так же можете посмотреть в сторону `paramiko` (вин10 может в ssh)